# Static variable is not working in runnable jar (hadoop mapreduce)

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, static

I am new in hadoop. I'm trying to *use a static variable* in my *mapper*.
I declare static variable in my main class

```
public static String var="";
```

After that i am giving some dynamic value in my main()
    var="123456";
and after that this variable i use in map() within mapper class

but it give me ***nullpointerException***.
when i use Eclipse, i'm able to perform in normal java core project with maven dependencies But when i make it runnable jar and it
run on hadoop server it give me **nullPointerException**
so i am still confuse why it give this exception anybody know this please help me

Thanks in advance

my main Class code

```
public class Tester {
    public static String var;

    public static void main(String args){
        var="12345";
        //calling mapper by job 
    }
}
```

and this my mapper class code

```
public class MyMapper {
    public void map(ByteBuffer key,SortedMap<ByteBuffer, Column> column,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        //now i want to use var variable here
        String str = Tester.var;
        System.out.println("Variable value   "+str);//this will give me nullPointerException in runnable jar
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add more information please

Comment: Please post the snippet of code where `var` is being declared and where it's being used.

Comment: ok dude i do give me minute

Comment: you intend to pass user defined variable to map function?

Comment: can you please give some hint how to intend to pass user defined variable to map function?

Comment: this will only for mapper and reducer if i want to use in another class than

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that Tester Class is your Hadoop job driver class. Then you need to do the following:

```
public class Tester {
 public static String var;

 public static void main(String args){
    var="12345";
       .
       .
       .

    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
    conf.set("varProp" , var);
       .
       .
       .
 }
}    

public class MyMapper {
  public void map(ByteBuffer key,SortedMap<ByteBuffer, Column> column,Context   context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
    //now i want to use var variable here
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    String str = conf.getString("varProp");
 }
}
```

If you want to initialize your variable in the mapper itself, you should do it in the override setup() method (not in the main because the main method will not be called at all) like the following .

```
public class MyMapper {
public static String var;
@Override
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException { 
        super.setup(context);
        var="12345";
  }
}
```